# WordPress Login redirection according to user role

Tags: login, user-roles, user-access

In my application a user needs to 1stlogin and is then able to access the website.

There are 3 different user roles in use on my site

> 1. administrator
> 2. editor
> 3. contributor

User can login from

```
http://example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php
```

*No login from any theme template.*

I have found this code, but it doesn't work

```
function my_login_redirect_contributors() {
  if ( current_user_can('contributor') ){
      return 'url-to-redirect-to';
  }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect_contributors');
```

---

*Note: I do not want to use plugin like Peter's Login Redirect. I want to achieve it by customizing wp core code with a filter.*

Comment: Why is the code you posted not working?

Comment: @m0r7if3r Ops its just for an idea

Comment: I gathered. What specifically about it is failing, because that code looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the filter **wrong**. If you got more than one `@param`, then you have to state them when adding the filter.

```
function wpse40745_redirect_on_login( $redirect_to, isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ), $user )
{
    # uncomment the following line if it's not working and replace $user->roles[0] with something that works
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r( $user ); echo '</pre>'; exit;

    if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'contributer', 'whatever_other_role ) ) )
        return home_url();

    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse40745_redirect_on_login', 20, 3 );
```